# using pandas and numpy to parametrize stack overflow's number of users and reputation

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I noticed that Stack Overflow's number of users and their reputation follows an interesting distribution. I created a **pandas DF** to see if I could create a **parametric fit**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
soDF = pd.read_excel('scores.xls')
print soDF
```

Which returns this:

```
    total_rep    users
0           1  4364226
1         200   269110
2         500   158824
3        1000    90368
4        2000    48609
5        3000    32604
6        5000    18921
7       10000     8618
8       25000     2802
9       50000     1000
10     100000      334
```

If I graph this, I obtain the following chart:

[image: stack overflow users and reputation]

The distribution seems to follow a **[Power Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law)**. So to better visualize it, I added the following:

```
soDF['log_total_rep'] = soDF['total_rep'].apply(np.log10)
soDF['log_users'] = soDF['users'].apply(np.log10)
soDF.plot(x='log_total_rep', y='log_users')
```

Which produced the following:
[image: Stack Overflow users and reputation follows a power law]

Is there an easy way to use pandas to find the best fit to this data? Although the fit looks linear, perhaps a polynomial fit is better since now I am dealing in logarithmic scales.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NumPy has a lot of functions to do fitting. For polynomial fits, we use **numpy.polyfit** ([documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)).

Initalize your dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [k.split() for k in '''0           1  4364226
1         200   269110
2         500   158824
3        1000    90368
4        2000    48609
5        3000    32604
6        5000    18921
7       10000     8618
8       25000     2802
9       50000     1000
10     100000      334'''.split('\n')]

soDF = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('index', 'total_rep', 'users'))

soDF['total_rep'] = pd.to_numeric(soDF['total_rep'])
soDF['users'] = pd.to_numeric(soDF['users'])

soDF['log_total_rep'] = soDF['total_rep'].apply(np.log10)
soDF['log_users'] = soDF['users'].apply(np.log10)
soDF.plot(x='log_total_rep', y='log_users')
```

Fit a 2nd-degree polynomial

```
coefficients = np.polyfit(soDF['log_total_rep'] , soDF['log_users'], 2)

print "Coefficients: ", coefficients
```

Next, let's plot the original + fit:

```
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
xp = np.linspace(-2, 6, 100)

plt.plot(soDF['log_total_rep'], soDF['log_users'], '.', xp, polynomial(xp), '-')
```

[image: polynomial fit]

Comment: Excellent answer and illustration of steps; I added the image inline. Thank you very much Jos.

Answer (score 10):

### `python`, `pandas`, and `scipy`, oh my!

The scientific python ecosystem has several complimentary libraries.  No one library does everything, by design.  `pandas` provides tools to manipulate table-like data and timeseries.  However, it deliberately doesn't include the type of functionality you're looking for.

For fitting statistical distributions, you'd typically use another package such as `scipy.stats`.

However, in this case, we don't have the "raw" data (i.e. a long sequence of reputation scores).  Instead we have something similar to a histogram. Therefore, we'll need to fit things at a bit lower level than `scipy.stats.powerlaw.fit`.

---

### Stand-alone example

For the moment, let's drop `pandas` entirely.  There aren't any advantages to using it here, and we'd quickly wind up converting the dataframe to other data structures anyway.  `pandas` is great, it's just overkill for this situation.

As a quick stand-alone example to reproduce your plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_rep = [1, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 10000,
             25000, 50000, 100000]
num_users = [4364226, 269110, 158824, 90368, 48609, 32604, 
             18921, 8618, 2802, 1000, 334]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(total_rep, num_users)
ax.set(xlabel='Total Reputation', ylabel='Number of Users',
       title='Log-Log Plot of Stackoverflow Reputation')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

### What does this data represent?

Next, we need to know what we're working with.  What we've plotted is similar to a histogram, in that it's raw counts of the number of users at a given reputation level.  However, note the little "+" beside each bin the reputation table. This means that, for example, 2082 users have a reputation score of 25000 *or greater*.

Our data is basically an estimate of the complimentary cumulative distribution function (CCDF), in the same sense that a histogram is an estimate of the probability distribution function (PDF).  We'll just need to normalize it by the total number of users in our sample to get an estimate of the CCDF. In this case, we can simply divide by the first element of `num_users`.  Reputation can never be less than 1, so 1 on the x-axis corresponds to a probability of 1 by definition.  (In other cases, we'd need to estimate this number.) As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_rep = np.array([1, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 10000,
                      25000, 50000, 100000])
num_users = np.array([4364226, 269110, 158824, 90368, 48609, 32604, 18921,
                      8618, 2802, 1000, 334])

ccdf = num_users.astype(float) / num_users.max()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(total_rep, ccdf, color='lightblue', lw=2, marker='o',
          clip_on=False, zorder=10)
ax.set(xlabel='Reputation', title='CCDF of Stackoverflow Reputation',
       ylabel='Probability that Reputation is Greater than X')
plt.show()
```

[image]

You might wonder why we're converting things over to a "normalized" version.  The simplest answer is that it's more useful.  It allows us to say something that isn't directly related to our sample size. Tomorrow, the total number of Stackoverflow users (and the numbers at each reputation level) will be different.  However, the total probability that any given user has a particular reputation won't have changed significantly.  If we want to predict John Skeet's reputation (highest rep. user) when the site hits 5 million registered users, it's much easier to use the probabilities instead of raw counts.

### Naive fit of a power-law distribution

Next, let's fit a power-law distribution to the CCDF.  Again, if we had the "raw" data in the form of a long list of reputation scores, it would be best to use a statistical package to handle this.  In particular, `scipy.stats.powerlaw.fit`.

However, we don't have the raw data.  The CCDF of a power-law distribution takes the form of `ccdf = x**(-a + 1)`. Therefore, we'll fit a line in log-space, and we can get the `a` parameter of the distribution from `a = 1 - slope`.

For the moment, let's use `np.polyfit` to fit the line.  We'll need to handle the conversion back and forth from log-space by ourselves:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_rep = np.array([1, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 10000,
                      25000, 50000, 100000])
num_users = np.array([4364226, 269110, 158824, 90368, 48609, 32604, 18921,
                      8618, 2802, 1000, 334])

ccdf = num_users.astype(float) / num_users.max()

# Fit a line in log-space
logx = np.log(total_rep)
logy = np.log(ccdf)
params = np.polyfit(logx, logy, 1)
est = np.exp(np.polyval(params, logx))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(total_rep, ccdf, color='lightblue', ls='', marker='o',
          clip_on=False, zorder=10, label='Observations')

ax.plot(total_rep, est, color='salmon', label='Fit', ls='--')

ax.set(xlabel='Reputation', title='CCDF of Stackoverflow Reputation',
       ylabel='Probability that Reputation is Greater than X')

plt.show()
```

[image]

There's an immediate problem with this fit.  Our estimate states that there's a *greater than 1* probability that users will have a reputation of 1.  That's not possible.

The problem is that we let `polyfit` choose the best-fit y-intercept for our line.  If we take a look a `params` in our code above, it's the second number:

```
In [11]: params
Out[11]: array([-0.81938338,  1.15955974])
```

By definition, the y-intercept should be 1.  Instead, the best-fit intercept is about `1.16`.  We need to fix that number, and only allow the slope to vary in the linear fit.

### Fixing the y-intercept in the fit

First off, note that `log(1) --> 0`.  Therefore, we actually want to force the y-intercept in log-space to be 0 instead of 1.

It's easiest to do this using `np.linalg.lstsq` to solve for things instead of `np.polyfit`.  At any rate, you'd do something similar to:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_rep = np.array([1, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 10000,
                      25000, 50000, 100000])
num_users = np.array([4364226, 269110, 158824, 90368, 48609, 32604, 18921,
                      8618, 2802, 1000, 334])

ccdf = num_users.astype(float) / num_users.max()

# Fit a line with a y-intercept of 1 in log-space
logx = np.log(total_rep)
logy = np.log(ccdf)
slope, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(logx[:,np.newaxis], logy)

params = [slope, 0]
est = np.exp(np.polyval(params, logx))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(total_rep, ccdf, color='lightblue', ls='', marker='o',
          clip_on=False, zorder=10, label='Observations')

ax.plot(total_rep, est, color='salmon', label='Fit', ls='--')

ax.set(xlabel='Reputation', title='CCDF of Stackoverflow Reputation',
       ylabel='Probability that Reputation is Greater than X')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Hmmm... Now we have a new problem.  Our new line doesn't fit our data very well.  This is a common problem with power-law distributions.

### Use only the "tails" in the fit

In real-life, observed distributions almost never exactly follow a power-law.  However, their "long tails" often do.  You can see this quite clearly in this dataset.  If we were to exclude the first two data points (low-reputation/high-probability), we'd get a very different line and it would be a much better fit to the remaining data.

The fact that only the tail of the distribution follows a power-law explains why we weren't able to fit our data very well when we fixed the y-intercept.

There are a lot of different modified power-law models for what happens near a probability of 1, but they all follow a power-law to the right of some cutoff value.  Based on our observed data, it looks like we could fit two lines: One to the right of a reputation of ~1000 and one to the left.

With that in mind, let's forget about the left-hand side of things and focus on the "long tail" on the right.  We'll use `np.polyfit` but exclude the left-most three points from the fit.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_rep = np.array([1, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 10000,
                      25000, 50000, 100000])
num_users = np.array([4364226, 269110, 158824, 90368, 48609, 32604, 18921,
                      8618, 2802, 1000, 334])

ccdf = num_users.astype(float) / num_users.max()

# Fit a line in log-space, excluding reputation <= 1000
logx = np.log(total_rep[total_rep > 1000])
logy = np.log(ccdf[total_rep > 1000])

params = np.polyfit(logx, logy, 1)
est = np.exp(np.polyval(params, logx))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(total_rep, ccdf, color='lightblue', ls='', marker='o',
          clip_on=False, zorder=10, label='Observations')

ax.plot(total_rep[total_rep > 1000], est, color='salmon', label='Fit', ls='--')

ax.set(xlabel='Reputation', title='CCDF of Stackoverflow Reputation',
       ylabel='Probability that Reputation is Greater than X')

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Test the different fits

In this case, we have some additional data.  Let's see how well each different fit predicts the top 5 user's reputation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_rep = np.array([1, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 10000,
                      25000, 50000, 100000])
num_users = np.array([4364226, 269110, 158824, 90368, 48609, 32604, 18921,
                      8618, 2802, 1000, 334])

top_5_rep = [832131, 632105, 618926, 596889, 576697]
top_5_ccdf = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=float) / num_users.max()

ccdf = num_users.astype(float) / num_users.max()

# Previous fits
naive_params = [-0.81938338,  1.15955974]
fixed_intercept_params = [-0.68845134, 0]
long_tail_params = [-1.26172528, 5.24883471]

fits = [naive_params, fixed_intercept_params, long_tail_params]
fit_names = ['Naive Fit', 'Fixed Intercept Fit', 'Long Tail Fit']


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(total_rep, ccdf, color='lightblue', ls='', marker='o',
          clip_on=False, zorder=10, label='Observations')

# Plot reputation of top 5 users
ax.loglog(top_5_rep, top_5_ccdf, ls='', marker='o', color='darkred',
          zorder=10, label='Top 5 Users')

# Plot different fits
for params, name in zip(fits, fit_names):
    x = [1, 1e7]
    est = np.exp(np.polyval(params, np.log(x)))
    ax.loglog(x, est, label=name, ls='--')

ax.set(xlabel='Reputation', title='CCDF of Stackoverflow Reputation',
       ylabel='Probability that Reputation is Greater than X',
       ylim=[1e-7, 1])
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Wow! They all do a pretty awful job!  First off, this is a good reason to use the full series when fitting a distribution instead of just the binned data.  However, the root of the problem is that a power-law distribution isn't a very good fit in this case.  At first glance, it looks like an exponential distribution might be a better fit, but let's leave that for later.

As an example of how badly the different power-law fits over-predict the low-probability observations (i.e. the users with the highest rep), let's predict Jon Skeet's reputation with each model:

```
import numpy as np

# Jon Skeet's actual reputation
skeet_prob = 1.0 / 4364226
true_rep = 832131

# Previous fits
naive_params = [-0.81938338,  1.15955974]
fixed_intercept_params = [-0.68845134, 0]
long_tail_params = [-1.26172528, 5.24883471]

fits = [naive_params, fixed_intercept_params, long_tail_params]
fit_names = ['Naive Fit', 'Fixed Intercept Fit', 'Long Tail Fit']

for params, name in zip(fits, fit_names):
    inv_params = [1 / params[0], -params[1]/params[0]]
    est = np.exp(np.polyval(inv_params, np.log(skeet_prob)))

    print '{}:'.format(name)
    print '    Pred. Rep.: {}'.format(est)
    print ''

print 'True Reputation: {}'.format(true_rep)
```

This yields:

```
Naive Fit:
    Pred. Rep.: 522562573.099

Fixed Intercept Fit:
    Pred. Rep.: 4412664023.88

Long Tail Fit:
    Pred. Rep.: 11728612.2783

True Reputation: 832131
```

Comment: Very nice. I was going to suggest scipy.stats.gamma. Raw data is available at http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/327447/reputation-distribution It doesn't do a very good job with the raw data either.

Comment: Great explanation Joe! I'll add the score and ranks of the top 5 users to my data frame and try to see the fit for a 4th degree polynomial, which was a good fit for my original problem (txs to Jos Polfliet). Thank you @ayhan for pointing out to where the raw data is, the log graph looks very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the excellent explanations of Joe Kington and Jos Polfliet, I decided to add to my data 5 data points from the tail end of the distribution (including the top user), to see if I could find out a single, good enough fit using just a polynomial fit.

Turns out that a 6th degree polynomial does an excellent job in the **center** and in the **tail** of the distribution, with less steps.

The chart below shows the data and the polynomial fit, which seems to be almost perfect:

[image]

### Adding tail end data points

This my df with some additional data points from the tail end of the distribution:

```
0           1  4364226
1         200   269110
2         500   158824
3        1000    90368
4        2000    48609
5        3000    32604
6        5000    18921
7       10000     8618
8       25000     2802
9       50000     1000
10     100000      334
11     193000      100
12     261000       50
13     441000       10
14     578000        5
15     833000        1
```

This is  my code:

```
soDF['log_total_rep'] = soDF['total_rep'].apply(np.log10)
soDF['log_users']     = soDF['users'].apply(np.log10)
coefficients = np.polyfit(soDF['log_total_rep'] , soDF['log_users'], 6)
polynomial = np.poly1d(coefficients)
print polynomial
```

Which returns this:

```
          6           5          4          3          2
-0.00258 x + 0.04187 x - 0.2541 x + 0.6774 x - 0.7697 x - 0.2513 x + 6.64
```

The graph is done with this code:

```
xp = np.linspace(0, 6, 100)
plt.figure(figsize=(18,6))
plt.title('Stackoverflow Reputation', fontsize =15)
plt.xlabel('Log reputation', fontsize =15)
plt.ylabel('Log probability that reputation is greater than X', fontsize = 15)
plt.plot(soDF['log_total_rep'], soDF['log_users'],'o', label ='Data')
plt.plot(xp, polynomial(xp), color='red', label='Fit', ls='--')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize = 15)
```

### Testing the parametric fit

In order to test the fit at the center, and at the tails, I choose the following profiles for users with rank 150, 25, and 5:

[image]
[image]
[image]
This is my code:

```
total_users = 4407194
def predicted_rank(total_rep):
    parametric_rank_position   = 10**polynomial(np.log10(total_rep))
    parametric_rank_percentile = parametric_rank_position/total_users
    print "Position is " + str(int(parametric_rank_position)) + ", and rank is top " +  "{:.4%}".format(parametric_rank_percentile)
```

So, for Joachim Sauer, this is the result:

```
predicted_rank(165671)
Position is 133, and rank is top 0.0030%
```

Off by 17 positions. For Eric Lippert:

```
predicted_rank(374507)
Position is 18, and rank is top 0.0004%
```

Off by 7 positions. For Marc Gravell:

```
predicted_rank(579042)
Position is 4, and rank is top 0.0001%
```

Off by 1 position. To test the center of the distribution, I test with my own:

```
predicted_rank(1242)
Position is 75961, and rank is top 1.7236%
```

Which comes very close to the real rank of 75630.

Comment: I tested with @Joe Kington and others, and it is pretty close.

Comment: @headdetective Thank you